# Duplicate extracted data not printing twice (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data stored in a text file formated as show bellow

```
counter name,coins weight,coins value,inputs corrrect
Jim,120,$1,Yes
Dwight,82,$1,No
Jim,130,$0.10,No
Dwight,82,$1,No
```

I used the following code to extract and print the data

```
info = {}
with open('CoinCount.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        countername, coinsweight, coinsvalue, inputscorrect = (
            item.strip() for item in line.split(',', 3))
        info[countername] = dict(zip(('coinsweight', 'coinsvalue', 'inputscorrect'),
                                (coinsweight, coinsvalue, inputscorrect)))

print('info:')
for countername, record in info.items():
    print('  Counter Name %r:' % countername)
    for field, value in record.items():
        print('    %s: %s' % (field, value))
```

However this code doesn’t print duplicate entries witch I would like to do. If anyone knows how to include duplicates help would be appreciated.

Expected output

```
Counter Name 'Jim':
coinsweight: 120
coinsvalue: $1
inputscorrect: Yes
Counter Name 'Dwight':
coinsweight: 82
coinsvalue: $1
inputscorrect: No
Counter Name 'Jim':
coinsweight: 130
coinsvalue: $0.10
inputscorrect: No
Counter Name 'Dwight':
coinsweight: 82
coinsvalue: $1
inputscorrect: No
```

Acctal output

```
Counter Name 'Jim':
coinsweight: 130
coinsvalue: $0.10
inputscorrect: No
Counter Name 'Dwight':
coinsweight: 82
coinsvalue: $1
inputscorrect: No
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you discard duplicates by writing twice in the same dict key. What do you want to do when a dupe is encountered? add? merge? please show expected output.

Comment: The actual output is correct

Answer (score 0):

Like Dirks Senne say, Python dictionaries is a data structure that can only hold unique values. So if you assign a new value to the same key (that can be only strings) you are overwrite the old value with the new one.
For example:

```
countries = {"USA": "America", "France": "Europe"}
print(countries)

countries["USA"] = "Europe"
print(countries)
```

results in

```
#Before the assignment
{'USA': 'America', 'France': 'Europe'}
#After the assignment
{'USA': 'Europe', 'France': 'Europe'}
```

### Possible ways to mantain duplicates

If you want to mantain duplicates, you can create a list of elements where each element is a different dictionary or using a different key (like and id number, not country name) and don't consider it when printing.

Answer (score -1):

Python dictionaries can only hold unique values as keys. You're trying to give the same keys different values, which will overwrite them. Consider using a different data structure.